# Error with curl on mac (curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.kyber.network) )

Tags: curl

I am trying to return a list of all possible tokens to trade on kyberswap using restful api from kyberswap docs.

The following

curl "https://api.kyber.network/currencies"

returns the following error:

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.kyber.network

Any suggestions?

Comment: `api.kyber.network` is a legacy endpoint and is already deprecated